# How to add quad curve segments to a straight line with dot views using pan gesture in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations

**Description**:
I am currently working on a Swift project where I need to implement a drawing feature that allows the user to draw a straight line using a pan gesture, and add up to two dot views on the line. After adding a dot view, I want to implement the following functionalities:

1. The first dot added to the line should be movable along the start and end points of the line, and a quad curve segment should be drawn between the start and end points when the dot is moved.
2. If a second dot is added, it should be movable along the straight line as well, and a quad curve segment should be drawn between the nearest dot and nearest start/end points.
3. When a dot is moved, the corresponding quad curve segment should be updated accordingly.

Could someone please provide guidance or sample code on how to implement these functionalities in Swift?

I have already implemented the logic to draw a quad curve segment between the start and end points of the line when a dot is added. However, I am having difficulty implementing the functionalities mentioned above.

The PolyViewController class has two properties:
activeLineView and activeDotView. activeLineView represents the currently active line view that the user is drawing. activeDotView represents the currently active dot view that the user is dragging.

The viewDidLoad() method adds two gesture recognizers to the view: a UIPanGestureRecognizer and a UITapGestureRecognizer. The handlePan(*:) method is called when the pan gesture is recognized and it updates the position of the active dot view if there is one. If the nearest dot view to the active dot view changes, the quad curve is updated. The handleTap(*:) method is called when the tap gesture is recognized and it creates a dot view and adds it to the line view if the tap location is on a line view.

The getNearestDotView(to:) method returns the dot view closest to the specified dot view on the same line.
Overall, this code implements a simple drawing application that allows the user to draw lines and add dots to the lines.

```
class PolyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var activeLineView: LineNewView?
    var activeDotView: DotView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
        
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }
    
// dot to drag an using pan gesture
 @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let dotView = activeDotView {
            // Handle dot view drag gesture
            
            switch gestureRecognizer.state {
            case .began:
                dotView.isDragging = true
                
            case .changed:
                // Update dot view position based on pan gesture translation
                let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)
                dotView.center.x += translation.x
                dotView.center.y += translation.y
                gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
                
                // Get the nearest dot view
                let nearestDotView = getNearestDotView(to: dotView)
                
                // If the nearest dot view is not the same as the active dot view, update the quad curve
                if nearestDotView != activeDotView {
                    activeDotView = nearestDotView
                    
                    // Update the quad curve
                    if let lineView = dotView.lineView {
                        lineView.setNeedsDisplay()
                        lineView.updatePath()
                    }
                }
                
            case .ended, .cancelled:
                dotView.isDragging = false
                
            default:
                break
            }
        }  
// line to draw an using pan gesture
else {
            // Handle line draw gesture
            switch gestureRecognizer.state {
            case .began:
                // Create new line view and add it to the view hierarchy
                let lineView = LineNewView(frame: view.bounds)
                view.addSubview(lineView)
                activeLineView = lineView
                
                // Set start point of the line view
                let startPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
                lineView.startPoint = startPoint
                lineView.endPoint = startPoint
                
            case .changed:
                // Update end point of the line view
                let endPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
                activeLineView?.endPoint = endPoint
                activeLineView?.setNeedsDisplay()
                
            case .ended, .cancelled:
                // Reset active line view
                activeLineView = nil
                
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

 // Handle tap gesture to display dot views on the line
    @objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
        for lineView in view.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? LineNewView }) {
            if let startPoint = lineView.startPoint, let endPoint = lineView.endPoint {
                // Check if there are already two dots on the line view
                if lineView.subviews.filter({ $0 is DotView }).count >= 2 {
                    return
                }
                
                let dotSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
                let dotSpacing = hypot(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / CGFloat(lineView.subviews.count + 1) // Calculate spacing based on current number of dot views
                let dotX = startPoint.x + (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) * ((location.y - startPoint.y) / (endPoint.y - startPoint.y))
                let dotY = location.y
                let dotOrigin = CGPoint(x: dotX - dotSize.width / 2, y: dotY - dotSize.height / 2)
                let dotView = DotView(frame: CGRect(origin: dotOrigin, size: dotSize))
                dotView.backgroundColor = .red
                dotView.layer.cornerRadius = dotSize.width / 2
                dotView.lineView = lineView
                lineView.addSubview(dotView)
                lineView.dotViews.append(dotView)
                lineView.updatePath()
                activeDotView = dotView
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func getNearestDotView(to dotView: DotView) -> DotView? {
        var nearestDotView: DotView?
        var nearestDistance: CGFloat = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        
        if let lineView = dotView.lineView {
            for otherDotView in lineView.dotViews where otherDotView != dotView {
                let dx = dotView.center.x - otherDotView.center.x
                let dy = dotView.center.y - otherDotView.center.y
                let distance = hypot(dx, dy)
                
                if distance < nearestDistance {
                    nearestDotView = otherDotView
                    nearestDistance = distance
                }
            }
        }
        
        return nearestDotView
    }
/// Dot view :

class DotView: UIView {
    
    var lineView: LineNewView?
    var isFirstDot: Bool = false
    var isLastDot: Bool = false
    var isDragging = false
    var controlPoint: CGPoint?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDotPan(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let controlPoint = controlPoint else {
            return
        }
        
        // Draw a curve from the dot view's center to the control point
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: center)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: controlPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (center.x + controlPoint.x) / 2, y: (center.y + controlPoint.y) / 2))
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.stroke()
    }
    
    @objc func handleDotPan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
           guard let dotView = gestureRecognizer.view as? DotView else {
               return
           }
           
           switch gestureRecognizer.state {
           case .began:
               // Set flag to indicate that the dot view is being dragged
               dotView.isDragging = true
               
           case .changed:
               // Update dot view position based on pan gesture translation
               let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
               dotView.center.x += translation.x
               dotView.center.y += translation.y
               gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
               
               // Update control point of the line view to match the position of the dot view
               if let lineView = dotView.lineView {
                   let dotPosition = dotView.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: lineView)
                   lineView.controlPoint = dotPosition
                   lineView.setNeedsDisplay()
               }
               
           case .ended, .cancelled:
               // Reset flag to indicate that the dot view is no longer being dragged
               dotView.isDragging = false
               
           default:
               break
           }
       }
   }

//LineView :

class LineNewView: UIView {
    var startPoint: CGPoint?
    var endPoint: CGPoint?
    var controlPoint: CGPoint?

    var dotViews: [DotView] = [] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let startPoint = startPoint, let endPoint = endPoint else { return }
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        if dotViews.count > 0 {
            // Find the nearest dot to the start point and add a curve from start point to the dot
            var nearestDotView = dotViews.first!
            var nearestDistance = distance(from: startPoint, to: nearestDotView.center)
            for dotView in dotViews {
                let distanceToDot = distance(from: startPoint, to: dotView.center)
                if distanceToDot < nearestDistance {
                    nearestDistance = distanceToDot
                    nearestDotView = dotView
                }
            }
            path.addQuadCurve(to: nearestDotView.center, controlPoint: controlPoint ?? midPoint())
            // Add curves between the dots
            var previousDotView = nearestDotView
            for dotView in dotViews {
                if dotView == nearestDotView {
                    continue
                }
                path.addQuadCurve(to: dotView.center, controlPoint: controlPoint ?? midPoint())
                previousDotView = dotView
            }
            // Add a curve from the last dot to the end point
            path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint: controlPoint ?? midPoint())
        } else {
            path.addQuadCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint: controlPoint ?? midPoint())
        }
        path.lineWidth = 5
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
    
    func updatePath() {
        setNeedsDisplay()
        
    }
    
    func midPoint() -> CGPoint {
        guard let startPoint = startPoint, let endPoint = endPoint else { return .zero }
        return CGPoint(x: (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2, y: (startPoint.y + endPoint.y) / 2)
    }
    

    func distance(from point1: CGPoint, to point2: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let xDist = point2.x - point1.x
        let yDist = point2.y - point1.y
        return sqrt(xDist * xDist + yDist * yDist)
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
   

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Without your `LineNewView` and `DotView` classes, it's unlikely we can help. See [mre].

Comment: i update the LineNewView and DotView classes in above code block @DonMag

Comment: OK - I can run your code. First pan draws a line... Tap on line to add a "dot" (red square)... Tap on line again to add a second "dot". At this point, are the dots supposed to be the control points for a quad curve from the start to end points of the line?

Comment: yes , what i did is an two dot points if i have two dot i drag either the first or second dot  cgpoints it access the whole start to end points .    my requirements is an based on if i drag the first dot the curve form between nearest of start points and nearest of second dot same as well as  the if i drag the second dot the curve form an nearest of first dot and nearest end points @DonMag

Comment: It might help if you provide a few images to better explain your goal... for example, are you trying to do something like this -- blue "line" ... green and red "dots" ... curve from start to end of line, using dots as control points? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEIF8.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpbp.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KhDX.jpg  , if i drag the dot 1, I need a smooth curve between start point and point 2. But I receive the curve like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT4R7.jpg @DonMag

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5edq.png -- *drag the dot 1, I need a smooth curve between start point and point 2* -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lyHA.png

Comment: yeah if we drag the dot should be on the line. Also, If we drag the p2(second dot ) the curve should form between the p1(first dot) and the end point, at the same time, the curve drawn from P1 and start point must be retained without changes. I want like this image . https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2PwQ.jpg  @DonMag

Comment: You'll probably need to do some calculations to get that functionality. I'd suggest heading over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `uibezierpath smooth curve through points`